# What signal does bazel send on test timeout?

Tags: signals, bazel

I'm reading through the bazel documentation in pursuit of locating what signal bazel sends to a test target when it exceeds the allotted time limit. I came across this piece of the documentation that is directly relevant to this question...

> If a test takes too long to execute, exceeds some resource limit, or the test runner otherwise detects prohibited behavior, it may choose to kill the test and treat the run as a failure. The runner must not report the test as passing after sending a signal to the test process or any children thereof.
>
> https://bazel.build/reference/test-encyclopedia#role-test-runner

I'd like to know what that specific signal is that is referenced in the part about *The runner...**sending a signal** to the test process*.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the timeout signature in a py_test case I'm thinking we're dealing with a sigterm, which makes sense.

```bash
function signal_children {
  local signal="${1-}"
  if [ "${signal}" = "SIGTERM" ]; then
    echo "-- Test timed out at $(date +"%F %T %Z") --"
  fi
```

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/c5ec07ba3f2184c99b6468d905177cc20ecce00a/tools/test/test-setup.sh#L273

That message matches the timeout text I'm seeing in my test case.

```
==================== Test output for //projX:test_module_foo:
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.xx, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-0.13.1 -- python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
collecting ... collected 40 items

projX/test_module_foo.py::test_case_bar ERROR [  2%]-- Test timed out at 2022-07-22 06:27:07 UTC --
================================================================================

TIMEOUT: //projX:test_module_foo (Summary)
...
(06:27:08) INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 8 total actions
//projX:test_module_foo                               TIMEOUT in 2400.6s

Executed 1 out of 1 test: 1 fails locally.
(06:27:08) INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 8 total actions
```

Comment: what I'm really in pursuit of is how to get pytest to provide me with more information about what it had captured etc at the point of timeout because there's little visibility other than what managed to be flushed from pytest prior to the signal being received.
https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/5243